# How to find the length of a apex string variable inside visualforce page using javascript?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I have a visualforce page and an apex controller class. There is a string variable inside the apex class and i want to find the length of that string from visualforce page using javascript.

```
global with sharing class SampleClass{
     public String sampleString{get; set;}

     /***rest of the code**/
}


<apex:page showHeader="false"
           controller="SampleClass">

     <!--rest of the code-->

     <script type="text/javascript">

          /**code**/

         console.log('LENGTH: ' + ({!sampleString}).length);

    </script>

</apex:page>
```

When I run the above code, this: `LENGTH: undefined` is what i am getting. And I have already checked whether there is value inside the string.  `sampleString` is not null and it has value inside it. So, what am i doing wrong? Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to do this in Javascript? If sampleString is set in your controller, you could just `system.debug(sampleString.length());` That aside, the Javascript property you're looking for is `length`, not `size`

Comment: ya i meant `length`. I just checked if `size` was working and forget to change it back before copying the code. And also yes, I have to check it in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use {!LEN(sampleString)}

Comment: thnks.. it worked

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted the actual string:

```
let sampleString = "{!JSENCODE(sampleString)}";
console.log(sampleString.length);
```

You need to make sure you put the string in quotes, and also use JSENCODE to make sure it doesn't get encoded incorrectly.

Comment: the other answer worked for me.. anyway thnks for helping.